# I would like to find a file with a specific name in one of two paths. The second contains an unknown folder

Tags: unix, search, find, command, line

I'm trying to search for a file: **logfile.log**

This file will either be in:

`/home/dir01/dir02`

Or:

`/home/something/dir01/dir02`

The problem is that directory 'something' can take any name, or it may not exist at all

From the home directory, I tried:

`find */dir01/dir02 -name logfile.log`

but this only works when directory something exists

I'm wondering if this is possible in one command in a reasonably efficient way.

It seems a waste to search all files from /home because I already know of the two subdirectories it must be in.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems a waste to search all files from /home because I already know of the two subdirectories it must be in.

Indeed, that's true. A simple approach to is to test the existence of one before the other and only proceed on failure:

```
for file in dir01/dir02/logfile.log */dir01/dir02/logfile.log; do [ -e $file ] && break; done
```